# Flex-box vertical centering doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using the following HTML and CSS. I just got familiar with flex box and followed [this tutorial](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/) to centre (both horizontally , vertically) some other HTML elements :

```
<div>
  <div class="page-center">
     <div id="target_div">
       <h2 class="text-center">Connecting to the server</h2>
       <div class="progress">
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" style {{width: '100%'}}></div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div> 
</div>

     .page-center {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        max-height: 100%;
      }
```

The elements inside `target_div` are centered horizontally but not vertically.
Any idea why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you're setting the max-height of the div to be 100%. What you want is to set the min-height to be 100%. If that doesn't fix the problem, make sure you've set the height of the html and body elements to be 100% as well using:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Refer to http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYPGLL to see it work. Notice how if we remove the styling for html and body, the "page-center" div shrinks to fit the content despite the min-height being set at 100%.

Comment: i think you should include `* {margin:0;padding0}` so it will remove the scrollbar - easier to see the result

Comment: It still doesn't work :
http://ariansnake.herokuapp.com/
https://bitbucket.org/arianhosseinzadeh/snakegame

Comment: That's because your "page-center" div is another 2 levels deeper than we though it'd be and its parent don't have a height set. Set the heights of those divs to be 100% as well and it should work.

Comment: Do you mean `min-height` ? I set it to 100% for html , body , and 2 `div`s  and still it doesn't work

Comment: I set height to 100% for those two `div`s and now it works

Comment: @bransonl : But what's the reason that `height:100%` which is defined in `body` style , is not passed to these `div`s ?

Comment: The `height: 100%` that was set for `body` doesn't affect its children as it only sets the height of the `body` element to be 100% of its parent, which is `html`. Since the `div`s did not have a height set, they defaulted to just fit its content. Since that becomes their height, when the `page-center` `div` was given the style `height: 100%`, its height becomes 100% of its parent, which is the `div` that shrunk to fit contents, resulting in the `page-center` `div` being only as big as its contents needed it to be.